# Access columns in a multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Second question in a day, I hope it's fine... I still spend quite some time trying to figure it out on my own and look quite a lot on the internet before using this website.

Anyway, I have a table like this one:

```
index = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
         np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=index)
```

```
first        bar                 baz                 foo                 qux          
second       one       two       one       two       one       two       one       two
A       0.895717  0.805244 -1.206412  2.565646  1.431256  1.340309 -1.170299 -0.226169
B       0.410835  0.813850  0.132003 -0.827317 -0.076467 -1.187678  1.130127 -1.436737
C      -1.413681  1.607920  1.024180  0.569605  0.875906 -2.211372  0.974466 -2.006747
```

To access the column indexed bar/one I can run either `df['bar', 'one']` or `df['bar']['one']`
However I would like to use a string such as 
`columns = ['bar', 'one']`
and then 
`df[columns]`
But this doesn't work: `"['one'] not in index"`
Any ideas?

Just to be clear, I would like to access the index in one operation that I won't have to change for different columns: `df[columns]`. What should `columns` be?

Comment: You access multi-index by pairs: `columns=[('bar','one')]; df[columns]`.

Comment: thanks. This was pretty obvious.